# Unable to read excel file and use the data as test data in test script

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I am new to Java Selenium and trying to take the input for login from from an excel file as test data (2 login details). However, i am not able to read the test data from the excel file and use it to login. Could someone please give me a code for that.

I tried the below code:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class Sample1 {
    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;
    XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    XSSFSheet sheet;
    XSSFCell cell;
  @Test
  public void f() throws IOException {
      File src=new File("C:\\Standalone\\TestData.xls");
      FileInputStream finput = new FileInputStream(src);
      workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(finput);
      sheet= workbook.getSheetAt(0);
      for(int i=1; i&amp;lt;=sheet.getLastRowNum();i++)
      {
          cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1);
          cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
          driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
          cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(2);
          cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
          driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
      }


  }
  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.get("c");
  }

}
```

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you then please `accept` it So it might helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one very simple way to do that. Create one Class for reading the value based on given cell number

e.g. `ExcelFileReader.java`

```
public class ExcelFileReader 
{
        FileInputStream fis;
        XSSFWorkbook workbook;
        XSSFSheet sheet;

        public ExcelFileReader() throws IOException
        {
            // Read Excel File
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File("src/test/resources/SiteTestData.xlsx"));
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

            // To get Sheet 1
            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        }

        public String getCellData(int rowNum, int colNum)
        {
            return sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(colNum).getStringCellValue();
        }
}
```

Now in your test method call the `getCellData` method like

```
@Test
public void login() throws IOException, InterruptedException
{    
    ExcelFileReader read = new ExcelFileReader();
    String uname = read.getCellData(1, 0);
    String passwd = read.getCellData(1, 1);

    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(uname);
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(passwd);
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton")).click();

}
```